# Misplacing a return statement and character-int mismatch proofing

Tags: c++

I need help on  two parts. The gist of the program is that it creates a menu and takes a character input of L,P or Q. "L" initiates a function that determines if the given year is a leap year. "P" initiates a function that determines if the given input is a prime number. "Q" quits the program. The purpose of the program is to test our ability to call functions.

- The first problem is that I can't figure out where to place my return statements. It seems appropriate to throw them at the end of each function in order to return to the main menu, but this doesn't work. The functions just keep looping.
- The second problem is that there seems to be an infinite loop whenever a character is entered into the leapYear function or checkPrime function. ex: Entering ',' or 'o' to the prompt creates an infinitely looping error message. Is there a way to make it so that I can guard against non-numeric input to avoid this?
- I apologize for the formatting. I fidgeted with it for a bit to try to get that to work too. Guess it isn't my day.

// Project 12B

```
include <iostream>
include <string>
using namespace std;

 void displayMenu();
 void checkLeapYear();
 void checkPrime();
 char option = 'd';

// Beginning of the main function
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    // User input dialog
    cout << "Hello! This program provides two different services. "
        << "Entering the character 'L' will initiate a program that can determine if a"
        << " given year is a leap year.\n"
        << " Entering the character 'P' will initiate a program that will determine if a"
        << " given number is prime or not.\n "
        << "Lastly, entering 'Q' will quit the main program.\n\n "
        << "Please enter one of the following characters: L, P, or Q.\n\n";

    cin >> option;


    while (option != 'Q' || option != 'q'){
        displayMenu();
    }

    return 0;

   }


// End of main function




// The displayMenu function

void displayMenu(){

    // Switch statement for menu purposes
    switch (option) {

    case 'p':
    case 'P':
        checkPrime();
        break;

    case 'l':
    case 'L':
        checkLeapYear();
        break;

    case 'q':
    case 'Q':
        cout << "Have a nice day!";
        break;

    default:
        cout << "ERROR: You have entered a value beyond the specified range. Please limit your entries to either"
            << " L,P, or Q. \n\n";
        cin >> option;
        break;
    }
    return;
    }

// The checkLeapYear function

void checkLeapYear(){

    // Declaration of variables for checkLeapYear
    int lOptionYear;

    // User Dialog

    cout << "Hello! This part of the program determines if the year you entered is a leap year."
        << "Please enter a year.\n\n";

    cin >> lOptionYear;

    // Verification that the year entered is actually a valid year

    if (lOptionYear <= 0) {
        cout << "ERROR: You have entered an invalid year.\n\n";
    }

    // Actual leap year verification.
    if ((lOptionYear % 4 == 0 && !(lOptionYear % 100 == 0)) || lOptionYear % 400 == 0) {
        cout << "The year you have entered is a leap year. \n";
    }

    else {
        cout << "The year you have entered is not a leap year\n";
    }
    return;
   }

// The checkPrime function

void checkPrime(){

    // Declaration of variables for checkPrime
    int uNumber,
        factorCount = 0;

    // User dialog
    cout << "Please enter a natural number. The output will be the factors (if it is nonprime) of your input, and the "
        << "total count of factors (if they exist).\n\n";
    cin >> uNumber;

    // Guard against bad input
    if (uNumber <= 0) {
        cout << "You have entered a non-positive number. Please enter a positive, natural number \n\n";
    }

    // The loop starts at two and continues for as long as the iteration-variable is less than or equal to the input number
    for (int k = 2; k < uNumber; k++) {
        if (uNumber % k == 0) {
            cout << k << " ";
            factorCount++;
        }

    }
    // Statement telling total number of factors found
    if (factorCount > 0){
        cout << "\nThere were " << factorCount << " factors found. \n";
    }
    if (factorCount == 0){
        cout << "\nNOTE: The number you entered is prime. \n";
    }
    return;
    }
```

Comment: That loop condition in the `main` function, try to think about it for a little while, for example what happens if the user enters a lower-case `'q'` (here it helps to know about the [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) done by C++). Then think about when and where to read input from the user, and how to print the menu *every iteration*.

Comment: Oh and regarding those `return` statements at then end of your functions? Those are not needed, the functions returns anyway once you reach the end of them.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response @joachim-pilleborg. I understand (now) that `return` isnt needed in void functions.

Comment: Think about the *name* `displayMenu`, does it describe what the function does? No, the function does *not* display a menu so the function should probably be renamed (or removed, the code could easily be in the `main` function instead. However, you want to print the menu, get the input, and select action while the user don't want to exit, right? So place all that code inside the loop then.

Comment: And about the loop condition, like I hinted before, C++ uses *short-circuit evaluation* for the logical AND and OR operators. For an OR operation (using `||`) if the left-hand side is `true` then the right-hand side doesn't have to be evaluated. In your case, if `option == 'q'` that means that `option != 'Q'` is also `true` and the whole condition is `true`. You need to use the logical AND (`&&`) expression here instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1**: void functions are returned anyway so no need to place`return` or worry about them unless you want to terminate a function at midway.

**Problem 2**:

When cin encounters an input it can't properly read in to the variable specified (such as inputing a character into an integer variable), it goes into an error state and leaves the input in it's buffer.

You have to do several things to properly handle this scenario.

1. You have to test for this error state.
2. You have to clear the error state.
3. You have to either alternatively handle the input data that generated the error state, or flush it out and reprompt the user.

So in function `checkleapyear` replace `cin >> lOptionYear;` with

```
while(!(cin >> lOptionYear)){   //test for error state
        cin.clear();            //clear the error state
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";    //repromt user
    }
```

NOTE:dont forget to add `<limits>`

**Problem 3**

In main() just adding
`while(option != 'Q' || option != 'q')` is not enough as input could be anything other than `l`,`p` or `q`. In place of taking input `cin>>option` in main take it in `displayMenu()` and just call it recursively in case of default:

```
void displayMenu(){

    cin >> option;   // added here
    // Switch statement for menu purposes
    switch (option) {

    case 'p':
    case 'P':
        checkPrime();
        break;

    case 'l':
    case 'L':
        checkLeapYear();
        break;

    case 'q':
    case 'Q':
        cout << "Have a nice day!";
        break;

    default:
        cout << "ERROR: You have entered a value beyond the specified range. Please limit your entries to either"
            << " L,P, or Q. \n\n";
        //cin >> option;
        displayMenu();   //recursive call
        //break;
    }
    return;
    }
```

NOTE: remove while() from main and just call `displayMenu()`